# PHP: Getting data out of an object

Tags: php, object

How can I get the `user_nicename` from this object?

```
BP_User Object
(
    [data] => stdClass Object
        (
            [ID] => 1
            [user_login] => NICENICE
            [user_pass] => $P$BwLHvV7zxcZZ/zW7MY0NXNSmANP.U5.
            [user_nicename] => NICENAME
            ...
```

And where can I find resources to learn this?

Comment: Yeah. Tried that but wasn't sure what I was looking for.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$variable->data->user_nicename
```

should work.

Comment: Thank you! Can you tell me what this is called/ where I could find explanations in php.net?

Comment: @christina "Classes and Objects" has a complete overview on OOP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php

Answer (score 3):

You can print by another way also

```
foreach($result->data as $newdata) //$result is variable that store raw data 
{
printf("name: %s, Pass: %s, nicename: %s <br/>", $newdata->user_login, $newdata->user_pass, $newdata->user_nicename);
}
```

Result will be

```
name:NICENICE , Pass:$P$BwLHvV7zxcZZ/zW7MY0NXNSmANP.U5., nicename:NICENAME
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this type data. And I have extracted data from the array like this.
[This type data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ek0u4.png)

```
$original = new DateTime("2023-04-28T14:51:12-07:00");
$data = json_decode(json_encode($original));
$time = strtotime($data->date);
echo $time;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).