# WordPress get_posts() is NOT returning template tags

Tags: wordpress

I want to get the latest 5 posts using WordPress `get_posts` function. I did the following:

In **functions.php** file I have added **extra.php** file which contain following code:

```
if( !function_exists( 'evertstrap_post' ) ) {
function evertstrap_post() {

        $args  = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'numberposts' => 5,
        );

        $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

        foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            echo get_the_title();
            echo '<br/>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

    }
}
```

Now, from **home.php** file I am calling `evertstrap_post()` BUT it's not get the latest 5 posts !!

**BUT**

If I directly put the code into **index.php** file then it's working.

How can I solve it?

Comment: Have you tried returning the output in `evertstrap_post`, and then `echo evertstrap_post()` in `home.php`?

Comment: @sundaycode I get same post 5 times. not 5 different posts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this sometimes in WordPress where `echo`ing the output is unfavorable. Could you give this a shot?

```php
if( !function_exists( 'evertstrap_post' ) ) {
function evertstrap_post() {
        global $post;

        $args  = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'numberposts' => 5,
        );

        $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

        $output = '';

        foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            $output .= get_the_title();
            $output .= '<br/>';
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();

        return $output;
    }
}
```

Then in `home.php` you could do:

```php
<?php echo evertstrap_post(); ?>
```

Comment: No luck. Same post 5 times.

Comment: @creativeartbd Could you try my newest edit? I'm seeing some docs saying the `global $post` is required after the loop.

Comment: @creativeartbd Awesome! I believe since you were not getting the `$post` globally, `get_the_title()` didn't know which post to grab from. This is why you were seeing the same post being displayed all 5 times.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
if( !function_exists( 'evertstrap_post' ) ) {
    function evertstrap_post() {

            $args  = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'numberposts' => 5,
            );

            $recent_posts = get_posts( $args );

            foreach ( $recent_posts as $post ) {
                setup_postdata( $post );
                echo get_the_title($post->ID);
                echo '<br/>';
            }
            wp_reset_postdata();

        }
    }
```

1. You saw only last post title 5 times because get_the_title() is a template tag used in "while post : do post" wordpress loop. However the same function accepts argument with post ID. more here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_title/
2. Getting posts via function get_posts() you store post obejcts in an array and using normal foreach loop you can retrieve object data using `$post->key_name` within this loop. [PHP: Getting data out of an object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392704/php-getting-data-out-of-an-object)
3. Also I recommend wordpress codex. Its very well documented.